# What does the 1000M on a network switch mean?

Tags: switch

I thought the 1000M ment that it was capable of Gigabit speed but it isn't, I noticed then that it stated 10/100Mbps. What does this 1000M mean?

[image: Network Switch 1000M vs 100Mbps]

Comment: Why do you say 1000m isn't 1000mbps?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> I thought the 1000M ment that it was capable of Gigabit speed

The 1000M is clearly labelling indicator lights showing that the ports in question are running at gigabit speeds.

> but it isn't, I noticed then that it stated 10/100Mbps.

Have you tested all the ports?

The line you highlighted part of says

"24 port 10/100 + 2 SFP/1000T combo"

"24 port 10/100" indicates that your switch has 24 ports that are capable of 10/100 speeds.

"2 SFP/1000T combo" indicates that your switch has two gigabit ports which can be used either directly for 1000BASE-T copper or used with a SFP module (for gigabit fiber).

Since only ports 25 and 26 have "1000M" lights it's pretty clear that ports 1-24 are the 10/100 ports and ports 25-26 are the gigabit ports. If you connect two devices to ports 25 and 26 you should get gigabit speeds between them. If you don't you might want to check the configuration to make sure noone has locked the ports to a lower speed.

It's very common in switches to have a couple of ports that are faster than the rest. This makes sense because in general you want your backbones to be faster than your access ports.

Comment: And just to add an answer to the title question.  1000M on a network switch usually means 1000 Mega bits per second, in reference to the physical speed of the port.  You seemed to know that though, you were just getting confused by only having 2 "up-link" or "backbone" ports on this switch.

Comment: @TafT, thanks, updated my port to more directly address the question.

Answer (score 42):

It looks like ports 25 and 26 are gigabit ports, while 1-24 are 10/100 Mbps ports. It's quite common to have a couple of 1 Gbps ports on 10/100 Mbps switches as uplink ports.

Answer (score 10):

Ports 25/26 are capable of 1000Mbps. These would appear to be combo SFP/Copper ports, which will only allow you to use one or the other.

Ports 1-24 are not.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that it has 2 SFP ports capable of 1 Gbps.

Answer (score 2):

The following excerpt is taken from the **Allied Telesis** website at http://www.alliedtelesis.co.uk/p-2122.html

> The WebSmart AT-FS750/24 features 24 10/100TX ports with 2 combo tri-speed copper/SFP ports for Gigabit connections.

As others have stated, those two ports only (25 and 26) are capable of operating at Gigabit speed, the others are 10/100.

Answer (score 0):

It means [1000 mega bits per second] or [1 giga bit per second] depending on how you refer to your network ports.

It is just a measure of the network speed.

1000M = 1000Mbp/s = 1Gbps

Answer (score 0):

You have two gigabit ports on that switch (10/100/1000), and the rest are 10/100.

If you're working on that network, I'd recommending future-proofing by upgrading to a switch where all ports are gigabit-capable, even if some of your devices may not be at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

24-Port 10/100Mbps labelled on the switch means that there are 24 ports which handle 10/100Mbps, and 2 SFP/1000T shows that this switch can support both optical (1000BASE-X) and copper 1000BASE-T SFP modules for 1Gbps uplinks.